# WPF Animation : How do i make it slide in?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, animation, storyboard

So I just got into animations and I wanted to do a "Slide out" animation and I managed to do so just fine.
But now I want it to slide in with the click on the same button.
So like I click it and it slides out and then I want it to slide back in when I click it again.

**WITHOUT any code behind, so just through xaml**

[image]

Here is the XAML

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.Resources>
        <Storyboard x:Key="TransformImage">
            <DoubleAnimation
                Storyboard.TargetName="MovingImage"
                Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Image.RenderTransform).(TranslateTransform.X)"
                By="130" Duration="0:0:0.3">
            </DoubleAnimation>
        </Storyboard>

        <Storyboard x:Key="TransformButton">
            <DoubleAnimation
                Storyboard.TargetName="btnChange"
                Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Button.RenderTransform).(TranslateTransform.X)"
                By="130" Duration="0:0:0.3">
            </DoubleAnimation>
        </Storyboard>
    </Grid.Resources>


    <Grid.Triggers>
        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Button.Click" SourceName="btnChange">
            <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource TransformImage}"/>
            <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource TransformButton}"/>
        </EventTrigger>
    </Grid.Triggers>

    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="0">
        <Image x:Name="MovingImage" Source="logo.png"
               MaxWidth="120">
            <Image.RenderTransform>
                <TranslateTransform />
            </Image.RenderTransform>
        </Image>
    </StackPanel>

    <StackPanel
        Panel.ZIndex="1"
        Height="450" 
          Width="120"
          HorizontalAlignment="Left"
          Background="Black"></StackPanel>

    <Button Margin="130,0,0,0" Height="40" Width="120"
            Content="Show Image" x:Name="btnChange"
            HorizontalAlignment="Left" >
        <Button.RenderTransform>
            <TranslateTransform />
        </Button.RenderTransform>
    </Button>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You need to store current state of slide animation when clicking on button and based on it run appropriate story board.

For example, you could use `ToggleButton` that has `IsChecked` property (or property in view-model).

*To avoid duplicate triggers/styles I placed Image and ToggleButton in the same StackPanel.*

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.Resources>

        <system:Double x:Key="SlideOffSet">130</system:Double>

        <Storyboard x:Key="SlideRight">
            <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TranslateTransform.X)"
                             From="0" To="{StaticResource SlideOffSet}"
                             Duration="0:0:0.3" />
         </Storyboard>

         <Storyboard x:Key="SlideLeft">
             <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TranslateTransform.X)"
                              From="{StaticResource SlideOffSet}" To="0" 
                              Duration="0:0:0.3" />
         </Storyboard>

    </Grid.Resources>

    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="0">
        <StackPanel.Style>
            <Style TargetType="StackPanel">
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsChecked, ElementName=SlideState}" Value="True">
                        <DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                            <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource SlideRight}" />
                        </DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                        <DataTrigger.ExitActions>
                            <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource SlideLeft}" />
                        </DataTrigger.ExitActions>
                    </DataTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </StackPanel.Style>

        <StackPanel.RenderTransform>
            <TranslateTransform />
        </StackPanel.RenderTransform>

        <Image Source="logo.png" MaxWidth="120" />
        <ToggleButton x:Name="SlideState" Margin="10,0,0,0" Height="40" Width="120" Content="Show Image" />

    </StackPanel>

    <StackPanel
        Panel.ZIndex="1"
        Height="450" 
        Width="120"
        HorizontalAlignment="Left"
        Background="Black"></StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

Also, I would not recommend using `By` property of the `DoubleAnimation`: 
If animation is still running and you click button again, then second animation will be started at wrong position (it will use X value from first animation, which is not finished) - Click button quickly many times and you will see the problem.

Use `From` and `To` properties instead.

Comment: Oh wow! I had no idea, thanks for all the great pointers! If I could upvote this twice I would!